# DSE 5.1.0 on windows machine

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

My Enviornment is Windows 7

Previosuly used apache-cassandra-3.0.9 on windows and now want to try
DSE which have inbuilt support of Graph database.

I downloaded dse-5.1.0-bin.tar.gz to understand DSE graph and playing with it for testing purpose.

There are no bat files in it for windows.

Is there a way dse-5.1.0 can work on windows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though Cassandra 3.0.x runs on windows, DSE does not support windows as a platform, per: https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/supportedPlatforms.html

I recommend you fire up a RHEL, CentOS, or Ubuntu vm or cloud instance if you want to kick the tires on Graph. If you're aiming to install DSE on more than one system, Lifecycle Manager in OpsCenter 6.1 has a point-and-click interface for doing so which might minimize your time on the linux command-line if you don't enjoy working in bash.

Disclaimer: I'm dev for LCM... so more than a little biased about that particular suggestion.

Comment: Update on this : there is new feature in Windows 10 called WSL BASH..Using that i am able to run DSE 5.1.0  successfully on windows. No need to install any VM.